# Conversion of string to date

Tags: java

I have a date in this format (Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 530 2016) which is a string and I want to convert this to a simple date format (dd/mm/yyyy).

I have used the below code but it does not work:

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmt123 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
 try {
     refDt = fmt123.parse(refDate);
     logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "date after parsing "+refDt); 
 }
 catch (ParseException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
 }
```

It gives me the result of: `Tue Feb 12 00:00:00 UTC 530`

How can I convert this?

Comment: you didn't define parser for `530` (also, what is it?) so it's parsed as a year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is a two-step process.

**Step 1 - Parsing existing string**

You are very close, but as you've noticed the 530 part (I guess it is milliseconds) is parsed as year.

Use following code to create the instance of `SimpleDateFormat` used for parsing

`new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z SSS yyyy")`

**Step 2 - Formatting**

Once you've parsed your date object, you'd need to present it to the user. Typically you would use `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` and use it to output the date. This will use your local machine settings (such as timezone) to do the formatting. Usually it is sufficient.

But this is far more complex...

- Timezones - the same time will mean a different date in different timezones. What is `2 AM, 11 Feb 2016 in Europe/Amsterdam` is `8 PM, 10 Feb 2016 in America/Boston` (or correct me if I am wrong).
- Different calendar - you've probably already heart about Gregorian, Julian or Chinese calendar. The same time moment might have different days/month or year if expressed in different calendars. Fortunately majority of time we're talking about Gregorian calendar...

There is a very nice article [Date and time in Java](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php) that describes the complexities in more details.

Answer (score 1):

## Poor Format

That String `Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 530 2016` apparently has a bad format. I assume the `530` is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). But it lacks a `+` or `-`, a serious omission. Also, while not required, a padding zero on a single-digit hour of an offset is advised (`05` rather than `5`).

FYI, `+05:30` is the time zone for two time zones, [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) and for [`Asia/Colombo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Colombo). See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). No time zone has an offset of `-05:30`.

I suspect this string may not actually be parseable as-is. You will need to manipulate the input string before attempting a parse. Something like the following, but your code will have to be more flexible if your input strings may vary.

```
String input = "Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 530 2016".replace ( "GMT 530" , "GMT+05:30" );
```

## java.time

The Question and other Answers use the old outmoded date-time classes. Classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The formatter codes in java.time are a bit different than those of SimpleTextFormat. Be sure to read the doc.

```
String input = "Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 530 2016".replace ( "GMT 530" , "GMT+05:30" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" );

ZonedDateTime zdtGmt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

### ISO 8601

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default in their `toString` method implementations.

```
String output = zdtGmt.toString ();
```

### Time Zone

Let’s adjust into the specific time zone of `Asia/Kolkata` rather than `GMT`. A time zone is an offset-from-UTC *plus* a set of past, present, and future adjustment rules for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtAsiaKolkata = zdtGmt.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | zdtGmt: " + zdtGmt + " | output: " + output + " | zdtAsiaKolkata: " + zdtAsiaKolkata );
```

> input: Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016 | zdtGmt: 2016-02-11T00:00+05:30[GMT+05:30] | output: 2016-02-11T00:00+05:30[GMT+05:30] | zdtAsiaKolkata: 2016-02-11T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Answer (score 0):

Your format here

```
SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

should match your input

```
"Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 530 2016"
```

As is mentioned in the comments this causes the parses to think 530 is the year and it ignores the rest.

See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details.

Answer (score -2):

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt123 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
try {
    refDt = fmt123.parse(refDate);
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "date after parsing "+refDt);    
}
catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While a code only answer solves the problem for the op, it isn't recommended as it provides no value for future visitors, a answer that only provides is quickly going to be flagged as "very low quality" and by the result of that it will be deleted quickly. [edit] your answer to include an explanation what the provided code does.